# Errors from libraries/Email.php

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform, codeigniter

After making a new form, using Free Form in EE, and adding the "notify" parameter, I get PHP errors. The data gets submitted, but the re-direct to the thank you page doesn't happen for the end user. It seems like if it sits for a day, then the redirect works, but the notification still doesn't happen. If I don't add the "notify" parameter, everything seems to work.

I didn't do the initial install of EE or FreeForm, so I don't know how it all goes together. Or how to trouble shoot. The hosting company recently switched servers, so I thought that might be the problem, but they updated permissions and don't think they are the issue.

Here are some examples of the errors:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Filename: libraries/Email.php

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using SMTP as your mail protocol, but either you haven't put proper credentials in, or your host doesn't support it. Try switching to Mail as your email protocol.

Comment: Got the same errors when sending a test from the Communicate page, so changed the email protocol to PHPmail (mail) and that fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be additional information if you turn on [**Enable Email Debugging**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/email_configuration.html#enable-email-debugging)

> When this option is enabled, detailed messages will be displayed whenever you send an email using the Communicate page. This information can be useful in helping to track down any problems you may be experiencing. If you are having difficulty sending email you are encouraged to enable this option.

Then sent test messages from the [**Communicate page**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/communicate.html) to see the debugging details.

---